# Using json_query to extract 2 variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to run this command but I need to extract 2 variables.

```
- debug:
    msg: my DB ARNs are {{ (registered.stdout | from_json)
       | json_query('DBInstances[*].DBInstanceArn') }}
```

I need the DBInstanceArn and the CACertificateIdentifier. I tried to use aws rds describe-db-instances but this didn't work as the CACertificateIdentifier isn't a valid filter. Basically I need to only target the RDS instances that are != to rds-ca-2019

Then I would register this data and then run `aws rds apply-pending-maintenance-action` and loop this through the previous registered data.  In this data I would only need the `DBInstanceArn`

Below is the upate with the code.

> This is the task that calls the API for the aws account number

```
tasks:

 - name: Get Account Info
      uri:
        url: "url"
        return_content: yes
      register: api
```

> I am now assuming a role in said AWS account that was located using the API call.

```
    - name: Assume Role for AWS Account 
      command: "aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::{{api.json.id}}:role/{{api.json.roles[0]|replace('[','')|replace(']','')}} --role-session-name {{api.json.env}} --output json"
      register: assumed
```

> From here I am setting the facts for the access key, secret key and session token.

```
    - name: Set access key fact
      set_fact:
        access_key: "{{ (assumed.stdout | from_json)['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'] }}"

    - name: Set secret key fact
      set_fact:
        secret_key: "{{ (assumed.stdout | from_json)['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'] }}"

    - name: Set Session Token fact
      set_fact:
        session_token: "{{ (assumed.stdout | from_json)['Credentials']['SessionToken'] }}"
```

> I am describing the RDS instances in the same account specifying the credentials

```
    - name: Describe RDS Instances
      command: "aws rds describe-db-instances --output json"
      environment:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{access_key}}"
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{secret_key}}"
        AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: "{{session_token}}"
      register: aws_rds
```

From here I am trying to get the `CACertificateIdentifier` So I may only target the rds clusters that have the value of `rds-ca-2015` or `!= rds-ca-2019`.  This was one attempt.

```
- name: Only arns I need
  debug:
    msg: item
   loop: "{{data}}"
   when: ( 'data.CACertificateIdentifier' != 'rds-ca-2019')
```

But this command returns both of the RDS clusters.

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=['arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:xxx:db:test-999', 'rds-ca-2015']) => {
    "msg": "item"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:xxx:db:test-888', 'rds-ca-2019']) => {
    "msg": "item"
}
```

This is where I am stuck.  I need to query the instances and only target the ones with a `CACertificateIdentifier` of `rds-ca-2015` or `!= rds-ca-2019`.

Thank you again for the help!!

Josh

Comment: Can you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your input data, the current result you are getting and the expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I need the DBInstanceArn and the CACertificateIdentifier."*

A: Try this to get a list of lists

```
- debug:
    msg: my DB ARNs are {{ (registered.stdout | from_json)
       | json_query('DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceArn, CACertificateIdentifier]') }}
```

or this to get a list of dictionaries

```
- debug:
    msg: my DB ARNs are {{ (registered.stdout | from_json)
       | json_query('DBInstances[*].{db: DBInstanceArn, ca: CACertificateIdentifier}') }}
```

---

> Q: *"Is there a way I can tell I am looking for `CACertificateIdentifier != rds-sa-2019`? "*

A: It's possible to use [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr) to select matching `data`. For example (*`= rds-ca-2015`*)

```
- set_fact:
    data_selected: "{{ data|
                       selectattr('CACertificateIdentifier',
                                  'match',
                                  '^rds-ca-2015$')|
                       list }}"
```

To filter out matching `data` use [rejectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#rejectattr). For example (*`!= rds-ca-2019`*)

```
- set_fact:
    data_selected: "{{ data|
                       rejectattr('CACertificateIdentifier',
                                  'match',
                                  '^rds-ca-2019$')|
                       list }}"
```

Comment: This worked and gave me the data.  Is there a way I can tell it I am looking for `CACertificateIdentifier != rds-sa-2019`?  Then register that data?

Comment: Are you aware of a way I can filter this correctly?  Every way I have tried has failed.

Comment: I have updated the initial question and added the code run.  Hopefully this helps!